# Can't display weather data using retrofit

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, retrofit

I'm trying to display data in my fragment & activity class from a Weather API using retrofit but on running the app, it displays nothing and meanwhile shows no error at runtime. I'm suspecting it will be due to a wrong connection of my retrofit network setup and I have no clue as to where the fault is, I need help, please.

I added Internet Permission in the Manifest

I also tried running the key on my browser online e.g https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=9.0765&lon=7.3986&exclude=alert,hourly,daily,minutely&appid= and it works but doesn't display data on my app

My codes are below:

**FirstFragment.java**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    public static String BaseUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/";
    public static String AppId = "(My App key)";
    public static String lat = "9.0574";
    public static String lon = "7.4898";
    // User current temperature, current condition, sunrise, sunset, temperature, pressure, humidity, wind_speed, visibility, UV Index
    TextView current_temp, current_output, rise_time, set_time, temp_out, Press_out, Humid_out, Ws_out, Visi_out, UV_out;
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public FirstFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment SecondFragment.
     */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FirstFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FirstFragment fragment = new FirstFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        current_temp = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        current_output = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView11);
        rise_time = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView25);
        set_time = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView26);
        temp_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView28);
        Press_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView29);
        Humid_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView30);
        Ws_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView33);
        Visi_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView34);
        UV_out = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView35);


                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BaseUrl).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
                WeatherService service = retrofit.create(WeatherService.class);
                Call<WeatherResponse> call = service.getCurrentWeatherData(lat, lon, AppId);
                call.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<WeatherResponse> call, @NonNull Response<WeatherResponse> response) {
                        if (response.code() == 200) {
                            WeatherResponse weatherResponse = response.body();
                            assert weatherResponse != null;

                            assert response.body() != null;
                            current_temp.setText(getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getTemp() + " ℃"));
                            current_output.setText(response.body().getCurrent().getWeather().get(0).getDescription());
                            rise_time.setText(getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getSunrise() + " AM"));
                            set_time.setText(getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getSunset() + " PM"));
                            temp_out.setText(getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getTemp() + " ℃"));
                            Press_out.setText(getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getPressure() + " hpa"));
                            Humid_out.setText(getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getHumidity() + " %"));
                            Ws_out.setText(getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getWindSpeed() + " Km/h"));
                            Visi_out.setText(getString(R.string.blank, response.body().getCurrent().getVisibility() + " m"));
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<WeatherResponse> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                        t.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
           return rootView;
            }


    }
```

**HomeActivity.java**

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static String BaseUrl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/";
    public static String AppId = "(My App key)";
    public static String lat = "9.0574";
    public static String lon = "7.4898";
    // User Timezone name, current time
    TextView time_zone, time_field;
    ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;
    public static int count=0;
    int[] drawable =new int[]{R.drawable.dubai,R.drawable.central_bank_of_nigeria,R.drawable.eiffel_tower,R.drawable.hong_kong,R.drawable.statue_of_liberty};
    Timer _t;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        time_zone = findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        time_field = findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BaseUrl).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        WeatherService service = retrofit.create(WeatherService.class);
        Call<WeatherResponse> call = service.getCurrentWeatherData(lat, lon, AppId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<WeatherResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<WeatherResponse> call, @NonNull Response<WeatherResponse> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    WeatherResponse weatherResponse = response.body();
                    assert weatherResponse != null;

                    assert response.body() != null;
                    time_zone.setText(response.body().getTimezone());
                    time_field.setText(response.body().getCurrent().getDt());

        constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dubai);
        _t = new Timer();
        _t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // run on ui thread
                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    if (count < drawable.length) {

                        constraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(drawable[count]);
                        count = (count + 1) % drawable.length;
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 5000, 5000);
    }
}

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<WeatherResponse> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {

                }
            });
    }
}
```

**My Interface**

```
public interface WeatherService {
    @GET("data/2.5/weather?")
    Call<WeatherResponse> getCurrentWeatherData(@Query("lat") String lat, @Query("lon") String lon, @Query("APPID") String app_id);
}
```

**EDIT**

Now it shows `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Integer com.tex.lightweatherforecast.first.Current.getDt()' on a null object reference` on runtime after i changed HTTP to https

My Current class:

```
public class Current {

    @SerializedName("dt")
    @Expose
    private Integer dt;
    @SerializedName("sunrise")
    @Expose
    private Integer sunrise;
    @SerializedName("sunset")
    @Expose
    private Integer sunset;
    @SerializedName("temp")
    @Expose
    private Double temp;
    @SerializedName("feels_like")
    @Expose
    private Double feelsLike;
    @SerializedName("pressure")
    @Expose
    private Integer pressure;
    @SerializedName("humidity")
    @Expose
    private Integer humidity;
    @SerializedName("dew_point")
    @Expose
    private Double dewPoint;
    @SerializedName("uvi")
    @Expose
    private Double uvi;
    @SerializedName("clouds")
    @Expose
    private Integer clouds;
    @SerializedName("visibility")
    @Expose
    private Integer visibility;
    @SerializedName("wind_speed")
    @Expose
    private Double windSpeed;
    @SerializedName("wind_deg")
    @Expose
    private Integer windDeg;
    @SerializedName("weather")
    @Expose
    private List<Weather> weather = null;

    public Integer getDt() {
        return dt;
    }

    public void setDt(Integer dt) {
        this.dt = dt;
    }

    public Integer getSunrise() {
        return sunrise;
    }

    public void setSunrise(Integer sunrise) {
        this.sunrise = sunrise;
    }

    public Integer getSunset() {
        return sunset;
    }

    public void setSunset(Integer sunset) {
        this.sunset = sunset;
    }

    public Double getTemp() {
        return temp;
    }

    public void setTemp(Double temp) {
        this.temp = temp;
    }

    public Double getFeelsLike() {
        return feelsLike;
    }

    public void setFeelsLike(Double feelsLike) {
        this.feelsLike = feelsLike;
    }

    public Integer getPressure() {
        return pressure;
    }

    public void setPressure(Integer pressure) {
        this.pressure = pressure;
    }

    public Integer getHumidity() {
        return humidity;
    }

    public void setHumidity(Integer humidity) {
        this.humidity = humidity;
    }

    public Double getDewPoint() {
        return dewPoint;
    }

    public void setDewPoint(Double dewPoint) {
        this.dewPoint = dewPoint;
    }

    public Double getUvi() {
        return uvi;
    }

    public void setUvi(Double uvi) {
        this.uvi = uvi;
    }

    public Integer getClouds() {
        return clouds;
    }

    public void setClouds(Integer clouds) {
        this.clouds = clouds;
    }

    public Integer getVisibility() {
        return visibility;
    }

    public void setVisibility(Integer visibility) {
        this.visibility = visibility;
    }

    public Double getWindSpeed() {
        return windSpeed;
    }

    public void setWindSpeed(Double windSpeed) {
        this.windSpeed = windSpeed;
    }

    public Integer getWindDeg() {
        return windDeg;
    }

    public void setWindDeg(Integer windDeg) {
        this.windDeg = windDeg;
    }

    public List<Weather> getWeather() {
        return weather;
    }

    public void setWeather(List<Weather> weather) {
        this.weather = weather;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if you added internet permission to the manifest. If it's not the reason - are there any errors in the logs?

Comment: I added internet permission in the manifest, no single error in the logs

Comment: try to use `https` instead of `http` for base URL .. not sure to post it as an anwer

Comment: @Zain Now it shows java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Integer com.tex.lightweatherforecast.first.Current.getDt()' on a null object reference on runtime after i changed HTTP to https

Comment: Add some logs or use debug to see if you're getting response in onResponse() callback and what are you getting there. You may parse response json incorrectly. Check if response is successful (status code 200)

Comment: @Alex.marynovskyi On my debug on logcat, I didn't see anything like (status code 200) after debugging neither did I get a response in onResponse() callback

Comment: Most probably (based on the exception you're getting) you're parsing json response incorrect. So, try to simplify it - parse only main entity (parent) with 1-2 fields and try to figure out where parsing went wrong

Comment: I fixed the error by changing the weather? to onecall? in my interface call. Thanks a lot for your contribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the error by changing the weather? to onecall? in my interface call